# If condition and Short circuit evaluation in rails - DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements, dry

I m doing an app and I need to add multiple condition if. I want to know if an solution exist to DRY.

I m tried something like this but that dont work, it's like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

```
  <% @camping.situations.each do |situation| %>
    <%if situation.plage == "oui" || situation.etang == "oui" || situation.lac == "oui" %>
    Do that
    <%else%>
    Do this
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

For my app to test more than 30 conditions so i dont want to repeat myself with multiple IF.

*Example :* Plage = oui / etang = Non / lac = oui
I want to display in my view :

```
Do that
Do this
Do that
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

### EDIT

I m sorry i think my message wasn't clear. So for each entries I have 3 possible value 1) OUI 2) NON 3) EMPTY. User add the value of his object.

So in my view i display like this

```
<% @camping.caracteristiquetests.each do |caracteristiquetest| %>
          <%if caracteristiquetest.animaux =="oui"%>animaux<%else%><s>animaux</s><%end%>
      <%if caracteristiquetest.barbecue=="oui"%>barbecue<%else%><s>barbecue</s><%end%>
      <%if caracteristiquetest.handicap =="oui"%>handicap<%else%><s>handicap</s><%end%>
      <%if caracteristiquetest.piscine=="oui"%>piscine<%else%><s>piscine</s><%end%>
      <%if caracteristiquetest.jeux =="oui"%>jeux<%else%><s>jeux</s><%end%>
      <%if caracteristiquetest.loisir=="oui"%>loisir<%else%><s>loisir</s><%end%>

    <%end%>
    <!--Affiche les parametres de la table situation-->
    <% @camping.situations.each do |situation| %>
      <%if situation.plage =="oui"%>plage<%else%><s>plage</s><%end%>
      <%if situation.etang =="oui"%>etang<%else%><s>etang</s><%end%>
      <%if situation.montagne =="oui"%>montagne<%else%><s>montagne</s><%end%>
      <%if situation.riviere =="oui"%>riviere<%else%><s>riviere</s><%end%>
      <%if situation.foret=="oui"%>foret<%else%><s>foret</s><%end%>
    <%end%>
```

If value is different to "oui" my view show Strikethrough.

I have more entries but it's always the same condition. As you can see i have lot of "IF". So i just wanna know if it's possible to DRY this ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. You have thirty conditions of the form `situation.foo == "oui"` where `foo` is an attribute?

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry for the explain. It's better ?

Comment: Your question is still confusingly incomplete... You say there are "30 conditions", yet you've only listed three. Are the other conditions all very simple? You also originally implied that one attribute must equal "oui", and now in your edit you've included a "non" - so could you clarify exactly what problem you're solving?

Comment: I also don't understand, even after the edit. Please give a concrete full example so people do not need to guess.

Comment: Also, your methods seems very odd. (In English,) they are saying `location.lake = 'yes'`, `location.pond = 'yes'`, .... Would it not make more sense to do something like: `%w(pond lake beach).include? location`?

Comment: @tomlord my 30 other condition are same. I have 2 value possible for each condition "oui" or "non" or empty. If my condition is "non" i want to write multiple sentence for  each "non". By thé way if condition is "oui" i want display sentence for each "oui"

Comment: isn't that exactly what I answered after your edit ?

Comment: Might I suggest you use `true` and `false`, instead of `"oui"` and `"non"`? You're just making things harder for yourself ;) E.g. `situation.plage? == true`. Or, alternatively, maybe just use `situation == "plage"`? What does "Do that; Do this; Do that" mean? - I thought there were only 2 branches in your condition, but now you mention 3... Or perhaps there are actually 30?! As I said above, please clarify your question; at the moment, we'd have to *guess* what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as follows.
The code `situation.members.any?{|m| situation.send(m) == 'oui'}` enumerates the members (attributes) of your situation object and compares the value of them each by doing a send of the membername against the string 'oui', if any of them contains it the whole expression is true.
The ternary statement ? evaluates this and puts the "Do that" if true and the "Do this" else.

```
situation = Struct.new(:plage, :etang, :lac)
situations = []
situations << situation.new('non','oui','non')
situations << situation.new('non','non','non')

situations.each do |situation| 
  puts situation.members.any?{|m| situation.send(m) == 'oui'} ? "Do that" : "Do this"
end

# gives
# Do that
# Do this
```

If I understand your last edit correct, this would become

```
situations.each do |situation| 
  situation.members.each{|member| puts situation.send(member) == 'oui' ? "Do that" : "Do this"}
end
```

You really should make your question more clear next time.
Based on your last edit, my last attempt, you just need to go one level deeper.
We just give you the methods how to do something, the rest is up to you.
More Dry than this it won't become..

```
camping = Struct.new(:situation, :caracteristiquetest)
campings = []

situation           = Struct.new(:plage, :etang, :lac, :montagne, :riviere, :foret)
caracteristiquetest = Struct.new(:animaux, :barbecue, :handicap, :piscine, :jeux, :loisir)

campings << 
  camping.new(situation.new('non','oui','non','non','oui','non'),
  caracteristiquetest.new('non','oui','non','non','oui','non'))

campings << 
  camping.new(situation.new('oui','oui','non','non','oui','non'),
  caracteristiquetest.new('non','oui','non','non','non','non'))

campings.each do |camping|
  camping.members.each do |camping_attr| 
    camping.send(camping_attr).members.each{|member| 
      puts camping.send(camping_attr).send(member) == 'oui' ? member : "<s>#{member}</s>"
    }
  end
end
```

Which gives

```
<s>plage</s>
etang
<s>lac</s>
<s>montagne</s>
riviere
<s>foret</s>
<s>animaux</s>
barbecue
<s>handicap</s>
<s>piscine</s>
jeux
<s>loisir</s>
plage
etang
<s>lac</s>
<s>montagne</s>
riviere
<s>foret</s>
<s>animaux</s>
barbecue
<s>handicap</s>
<s>piscine</s>
<s>jeux</s>
<s>loisir</s>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Unfornutualy it's not exactly what I want. I edited my answer.

Comment: It's not exactly that. I m sorry my answer wasnt clear. I edited. Thanks for your help